# In Python when writing to a file how can you make sure the data is saved on one line?

Tags: python, file, line

I have the following code:

```
with open("students2.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
    for each_item in names:
         student_grade=input("Enter the grade for " +str(each_item))
         my_file.write(each_item+", "+student_grade)
```

When the data saves to the file I need it to save like this:
each_item,student_grade so this might be Mike,78.
Then the next one is saved on a new line

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

```
 my_file.write(each_item+", "+student_grade+"\n");
```

Just use this to put it on a new line.

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, its still saving incorrectly. The comma and student grade are getting inserted on a new line.

Comment: Try converting each_item to a string.